# Rails Routing: Scoped controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a `ProjectsController` and a `SubmissionsController`. I want to set up my routes so that all of the **submissions** are prefixed by *projects/* however, after trying a variety of ways, I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I can set up the routes fine, they come out as intended, but it can't find my controller:

```
resources :submissions, only: [:index, :show, :create, :new, :edit, :update, :remove, :delete], path: 'projects/submissions'
get 'projects/submissions/:id/remove', to: 'submissions#remove', as: :remove_submission
patch 'projects/submissions/:id/delete', to: 'submissions#delete', as: :delete_submission
```

But it doesn't hit my `SubmissionsController`. Both my `SubmissionsController` and `ProjectsController` are within ***app -> controllers***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

The correct way is to write your route within a `scope` block

```
scope '/projects' do
  resources :submissions
end
```

And as your scope `/projects` has the same name as the routes of your `ProjectsController`, be sure to declare your `ProjectsController` routes after your `SubmissionsController` routes in your **routes.rb** file.

Comment: I've tried this previously (I should have said in the question) and had the same problem. It doesn't hit my controller

Comment: It works on my side (Rails 4.0.2). What means "doesn't hit your controller" perhaps a error stack could help

Comment: There is no error. It simply redirects to my projects_controller

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if I do this should work: in your routes.rb declare your projects_controller routes AFTER your submissions_controller routes

Comment: Argh, how frustrating, I just had them the wrong way round. Thanks!!